# How to handle AsyncTask without Internet?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

On My Login Page

When I Press Button, application crashes when i am offline. How to handle this?

```
public class Login extends Activity{

    EditText us,ps;
    String sus,sps,sh1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

     us=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
     ps=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button lgb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lgb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sus=us.getText().toString();
                sps=ps.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences shr=getSharedPreferences("kynum", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edd=shr.edit();
                edd.putString("sssnum", sus);
                edd.commit();

                if(sus.equals("")||sps.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                ilog lg =new ilog();
                lg.execute();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public class ilog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try
            {   
                String server = getResources().getString(R.string.server_add);
                DefaultHttpClient h=new DefaultHttpClient();
                ResponseHandler<String> respp=new BasicResponseHandler();
                HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost(server+"ilogin.php");
                List<NameValuePair>namevaluepairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", sus));
                namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", sps));
                postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
                sh1=h.execute(postMethod,respp);

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error:"+e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(sh1.contains("success"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Logged in.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usernmae or Password error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New User? Register First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);



        }

    }




}
```

I am also try most way to handle this but every time it have crashed and my log cat is

```
06-26 00:52:30.020: I/System.out(9732): Error:java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "equipz.orgfree.com": No address associated with hostname
06-26 00:52:30.020: W/System.err(9732): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "equipz.orgfree.com": No address associated with hostname
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:457)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
06-26 00:52:30.022: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:658)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:632)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:621)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at com.hackbal.custmrmgmt.Login$ilog.doInBackground(Login.java:89)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at com.hackbal.custmrmgmt.Login$ilog.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732): Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
06-26 00:52:30.023: W/System.err(9732):     ... 18 more
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732): Process: com.hackbal.custmrmgmt, PID: 9732
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:344)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:100)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at com.hackbal.custmrmgmt.Login$ilog.doInBackground(Login.java:95)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at com.hackbal.custmrmgmt.Login$ilog.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-26 00:52:30.044: E/AndroidRuntime(9732):     ... 4 more
06-26 00:52:32.110: I/Process(9732): Sending signal. PID: 9732 SIG: 9
```

I want show a Toast Message. What is the error, and how to remove it?

Comment: Seems to me that you're confusing the log message of the net connection with the one that's related with the crash. After failing to execute (which throws an exception that is only handled by printing in the log), the `if` statement in `onPostExecute` leads to your crash when showing the Toast. Make sure that the toast is being called from the right thread, with the right `Context`.

Comment: By the way, using default asynctasks for networking is a bad practise.You should execute it on executor, or use another concurrent mechanism. Or your tasks would be stucked in queue,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Alex you can check for Network availability before trying to connect to servers.

Like, here i have checked for network availability and showed a "No connection" `snackbar`

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Update UI here when network is available.

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (!(activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())) {

            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "No internet connection!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            isNetworkAvailable();
                        }
                    });
            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            sbView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.snackbar_back_color2));
            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            //textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();

        }
    }
});

return (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
```

}

Comment: Also try to check internet connection, but i want a proper handling for restrict app crash.

Comment: to restrict app crash you can use `try` and `catch` in `onPostExecute()` like you used in `doInBackground()`, but it will only suppress the current error not resolve it.

Comment: I can't help you with whole code because i don't know how much exactly are the errors.

Comment: How to know why application crash?, How to analyse logcat error?

Comment: I check for `Caused by:` in logcat. Most of the times that line is the real cause of error. If there are more than one `Caused by` that means you have multiple errors and try to resolve them from top to bottom

Comment: I think after reading your code and logcat, the error is in `try{ }` block of your `doInBackground()` method, where it cant resolve or reach. It says **`No address associated with hostname`** and it can't find **` Unable to resolve host "equipz.orgfree.com"`**. It means that maybe you are offline and it tries to go to that server but can't reach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115630/discussion-between-signoff-teamz-and-sahaj-rana).

Answer (score 0):

You can register broadcast receiver, which listen for 'change network state' event. If it happen when you processing http request, save this fact and try again later

Comment: Can you explain detailed?

Comment: Every time network state change (become avalaible 8r not)vsystem broadcast 8ntent for it. You can register BroadcastReceiver which will lesten for that event and if youre performing some actions now, mark those actions as corrupted (you'll get error), but handle this error as caused by network problems, not bad data

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're confusing the log message of the net connection with the one that's related with the crash.

After failing to `DefaultHttpClient.execute` (which throws an exception that is only handled by printing in the log), the `if` statement in `onPostExecute` leads to your crash when showing the Toast.

Make sure that the toast is being called from the right thread, with the right `Context`.

Comment: Can you please explain with details?

Comment: I think my application crashed, when i am offline.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger to see what is crashing? The log points to line 95 of `Login.java`. Make sure that what is crashing is the `Toast` or the network access.